# Why Flutter ListView only show first element?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

On my screen, I want to display a list of comments, but only the first item of the ListView is rendered even though I scroll the page.

Here is the code of my screen :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ofb_front/providers/sheet_provider.dart';
import 'package:ofb_front/models/sheet.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:ofb_front/widgets/comment_container.dart';
import 'package:ofb_front/widgets/sheet_images_carousel.dart';

class SheetScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SheetScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SheetScreen> createState() => _SheetScreenState();
}

class _SheetScreenState extends State<SheetScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //Sheet selectedSheet = context.watch<SheetProvider>().selectedSheet!;
    Sheet selectedSheet = Sheet(
        id: 0,
        title: "My Sheet",
        userId: 0,
        description:
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam sollicitudin libero vel augue laoreet porttitor. Donec efficitur neque turpis, id sodales neque posuere malesuada",
        photoLinks: [
          'http://projects.websetters.in/digg-seos/digg/wp-content/themes/twentytwenty-child-theme/img/demo-prof.jpg',
          'https://image.cnbcfm.com/api/v1/image/105992231-1561667465295gettyimages-521697453.jpeg?v=1561667497'
        ],
        longitude: 20,
        latitude: 30,
        createdAt: DateTime(2020),
        updatedAt: DateTime(2020));

    List _comments = [
      {
        "username": "John Doe",
        "createdAt": "3h",
        "img":
            "http://projects.websetters.in/digg-seos/digg/wp-content/themes/twentytwenty-child-theme/img/demo-prof.jpg",
        "content":
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam sollicitudin libero vel augue laoreet porttitor. Donec efficitur neque turpis, id sodales neque posuere malesuada"
      },
      {
        "username": "Jane Doe",
        "createdAt": "4h",
        "img":
            "http://projects.websetters.in/digg-seos/digg/wp-content/themes/twentytwenty-child-theme/img/demo-prof.jpg",
        "content":
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam sollicitudin libero vel augue laoreet porttitor. Donec efficitur neque turpis, id sodales neque posuere malesuada"
      },
    ];

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: false,
        title: Text(selectedSheet.title),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
          child: Column(children: [
            SheetImagesCarousel(
              selectedSheet: selectedSheet,
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Text(
                  'John Doe',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground),
                ),
                const Spacer(),
                Text('3h',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground))
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Flexible(
                  child: Text(
                      'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam sollicitudin libero vel augue laoreet porttitor. Donec efficitur neque turpis, id sodales neque posuere malesuada. Sed maximus quis ipsum vulputate varius. Donec condimentum elit vel neque placerat tincidunt. Donec sapien ex, mattis a consectetur a, ultrices quis velit. Nulla facilisi. Vivamus pellentesque, tortor mollis tempus hendrerit, ex tellus luctus nulla, at congue dolor magna quis leo. Mauris gravida est nec leo suscipit, et euismod erat vehicula. Fusce venenatis nisl in congue porttitor. Vestibulum pellentesque orci vitae sem tempor euismod. Sed risus nisi, pulvinar sed pulvinar vitae, vehicula ut libero. Nunc imperdiet lorem quis nibh hendrerit ultrices. Aenean molestie orci vitae magna hendrerit, ut luctus nisl tincidunt. Pellentesque posuere libero id lacus volutpat, et porta tortor dignissim. Ut tincidunt quam sit amet enim rutrum, sed vulputate mauris imperdiet.',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16,
                          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground)),
                )
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Commentaires',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                      fontSize: 22,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                const Spacer(),
                ElevatedButton(
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        foregroundColor:
                            Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary,
                        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary),
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: const Text('Ajouter un commentaire'))
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: _comments.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  var comment = _comments[index];
                  return CommentContainer(comment: comment);
                },
              ),
            )
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to wrap my ListView in an Expanded, but it still can take the full remaining height of the screen and display all the items of the list.

Comment: Why are you using `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would never show because of the following code.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
```

What's the whole point of using `ScrollView` if you are using `Container` of screen size.

---

Make these corrections:

1. Remove the `Container` and make the `Column` direct child of `SingleChildScrollView`
2. Now you have to remove the `Expanded` which is wrapped on `ListView`
3. Set the `shrinkWrap:true` in the `ListView`
4. Remove `physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` in the `ListView`
   It is because of this line   `physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()`